# How to get Insert id in MSSQL in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server

What the question title says. With a query such as `SELECT @@IDENTITY AS ins_id`, do I need to supply the table name or any other info to specify which table/database i'm talking about?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`@@IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) returns the most recent identity generated in the current session. In most cases you'll probably want to use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) instead, which returns the most recent identity generated in the current scope.

For example, if you insert a row into *table1*, but that insert fires a trigger which inserts a row into *table2*, then `@@IDENTITY` will return the identity from *table2* whereas `SCOPE_IDENTITY` will return the identity from *table1*.

```
INSERT INTO my_table (my_column) VALUES ('test')

-- return the identity of the row you just inserted into my_table
-- regardless of any other inserts made by triggers etc
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ins_id
```

Comment: I've also seen: SELECT CAST(COALESCE(SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @@IDENTITY) AS int)

Comment: Down voted. I dont see any php, the question was  "How to get Insert id in MSSQL in PHP".

Answer (score 1):

No; it works much like SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() in mysql, retrieving the last identity value inserted.  You may want to take a look at [this in-depth examination](http://www.kamath.com/tutorials/tut007_identity.asp) for more on what you might want to be concerned about with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code snippet somewhat based on Joomla code. $dbh is database connection (result of mssql_connect()). Key name (ID) is updated if you pass $keyName argument.

This code is using MSSQL keyword "OUTPUT" to get ID (or any required value) of inserted value.

```
function mssql_insertObject($table, &$object, $keyName = NULL)
{
    global $dbh;

    if($keyName) {
        $fmtsql = 'INSERT INTO '. $table .' ( %s ) OUTPUT INSERTED.' . $keyName . ' VALUES ( %s ) ';
    }
    else {
        $fmtsql = 'INSERT INTO '. $table .' ( %s ) VALUES ( %s ) ';
    }

    $fields = array();

    foreach (get_object_vars( $object ) as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v) or is_object($v) or $v === NULL) {
            continue;
        }

        if ($k[0] == '_') { // internal field
            continue;
        }

        $fields[] = $k;
        $values[] = "'" . str_replace("'", "''", $v) . "'";
    }

    $sql = sprintf( $fmtsql, implode( ",", $fields ) ,  implode( ",", $values ) );

    $query = mssql_query($sql, $dbh);

    if($query === false) {
        return false;
    }

    if(is_resource($query))
    {
        if($keyName) {
            $id = mssql_result($query, 0, 0);

            if($id) {
                $object->$keyName = $id;
            }
        }

        mssql_free_result($query);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution because I believe it covers all your bases since you can't get a GUID(pk) with SCOPE_IDENTITY ..but using mssql_result in conjunction with OUTPUT INSERTED in your sql statement works with pk's that are auto incremented integers or unique stings like GUIDs.