# how i can get the ID generated in the last query by php with sql server

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Insert id in MSSQL in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574851/how-to-get-insert-id-in-mssql-in-php)

how i can  get the ID generated in the last query by php with sql server, i know how do it by mysql
mysql_inserted_id but with sql server i cant pleass help

Answer (score 3):

You can try @@Identity.

```
SELECT ID AS LastID FROM Persons WHERE ID = @@Identity;
```

Comment: for more info http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/