# how i can get inserted id for sql server with php

Tags: php, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Insert id in MSSQL in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574851/how-to-get-insert-id-in-mssql-in-php)

im working in project by php and sql server 2000, how i can get inserted id like mysql_inserted_id function which work with mysql .
im googled in the internet and cant find something...please leave example to how use it

Comment: Apart from the Internet, always also search on Stack Overflow! See [How to get Insert id in MSSQL in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574851/how-to-get-insert-id-in-mssql-in-php)

Comment: How is this any different than [the last time you asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564875/how-i-can-get-the-id-generated-in-the-last-query-by-php-with-sql-server)?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() (which you can return via a SELECT statement) but the operator you use to get the latest ID depends on your implementation (your stored procedure may do more than one insert, for example, in which case @@IDENTITY would return only the latest ID).  Check out this explanation:

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/alternatives-to-identity-in-sql-server-2000