# How to get the number of next increment in mssql in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Insert id in MSSQL in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574851/how-to-get-insert-id-in-mssql-in-php)

I MYSQL I would do

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'image'
```

In mssql, sigh, I've no idea how to do it...

Please advice.. :)

Comment: You tagged this question with php, html, and jquery which have nothing to do with what you are asking.  In the future please try use tags that are closer to what you are asking.

Comment: Have you not noticed PHP in the title???

Comment: PHP isn't relevant here, because you're looking for the correct MSSQL query. It just so happens that you will be using PHP to execute it, but that's not where your problem lies.

Comment: @JamWaffles thanks, I was typing that but you beat me too it.

Comment: Alright, I just thought there might be some specific function... like... last_isert_id for examples...

Comment: Still, what are you asking? Are you looking for [number of rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) returned by the query? To get the last insert ID, you can use [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Comment: Suppose Identity has an increment by 50. Last ID is, suppose, 100.
So the value I want to retrieve is 150. In my sql I would use show status and then get the intval($row['Auto_increment'])

Comment: That's exactly how you do it, then. You can't do it just in PHP without querying the database because that's where it's stored. You can keep track of the increment and last ID in PHP and calculate it manually... but that's about all you can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this to get the NEXT identity.

`SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('image') + IDENT_INCR('image')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('image')
```

then add 1 to get the next.

It's better than using max(id)+1 because the latest id might have been deleted

Comment: You should also add  `IDENT_INCR('image')` to it so that you aren't hard coding the increment value in the application.

Comment: Yes great idea. I've never seen an increment value other than 1, but I suppose it can exist.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the max value +1. Something like

```
Select max(id)+1 from image;
```

Comment: Yes, but there should be some way to retrieve the identity increment as well. But thanks for the idea, will probably use it as a last resort

Comment: That will work if the increment is 1, which I'm not sure is the case with this. (from @user1125062's comment in question post)