# Insert primary key into another table with 2 separate inserts

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

My code is probably very sloppy and that's probably why I can't get this to work.  (Note: I'm using php.) I have 2 inserts on my page and I need to copy the primary key from the first insert and use it in my second insert. The primary key of CustBill_billing is 'bill_ID'.  Is there a way to output the primary key of CustBill_billing after it queries so I can use it on my second insert?

First insert:

```
    $sql="
INSERT INTO CustBill_billing (C_ID, bolNum, type, le, waybill_date, bill_type, bol_date, con_name, con_city, con_state, ship_name, ship_city, ship_state, contract_num, weight, weight_cd, weight_auth, edc, fsac, ind, stcc, rr_from, rr_to, paymentMeth, unlDcd) 
VALUES ('1', '$pbolNum', '2', 'L', '$today', 'L', '$pbol_date', '$pcon_name', '$pcon_city', '$pcon_state', '$pship_name', '$pship_city', '$pship_state', '$pcontract_num', '$pweight', '$pweight_cd', 'A', 'RR', '1', '$pind', '$pstcc', '$prr_from', '$prr_to', '$ppaymentMeth', '$punlDcd')
";
```

Second insert:

```
foreach($_POST['car_init'] as $key => $car_init)
{
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO CustBill_cars (C_ID, car_init, car_num, bolNum) VALUES ('1', '".$car_init."', '".$car_num[$key]."', '$pbolNum')
";
```

The reason I have them separate is because I have to loop the 2nd insert because of the auto-generated text boxes; it checks to see how many there are in an array and then inserts each new record into the CustBill_cars table. Each time it inserts, I need the primary key that was created from the first insert to insert into this second query in a field named 'carbill_ID'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Insert id in MSSQL in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574851/how-to-get-insert-id-in-mssql-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, if your Id field is an Identity then you can try SCOPE_IDENTITY(). For example:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(columns)
   VALUES(...)

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I made it way more complicated than need be.

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO CustBill_cars (C_ID, car_init, car_num, bolNum, bill_ID)
SELECT 1, '".$car_init."', '".$car_num[$key]."', $pbolNum, CustBill_billing.bill_ID
FROM CustBill_billing
";
```